# How to define the function type with an existing type in a more readable way?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

With a very simple and readable function like:

```
function signIn(...) {...}
```

To define its type with an existing definition `Action`, it becomes something that's not very readable:

```
const signIn: Action = function (...) {...}
```

That is a lot of changes, and not very readable, just to specify that the function is of the `Action` type.

I wonder if there's any way to not use the `const` and to keep `signIn` next to `function`? I realise I can copy the existing type definition `Action` and apply it directly to the function, but it's not good for maintainability – what if the original `Action` definition changes?

Comment: None that I'm aware of. I think it's perfectly readable, though. It follows the exact same typing syntax as other TS types, so once you get comfortable with those, it will be easier to read.

Comment: How does this question relate to vue/vuex? Maybe if you give better context a different solution could be found

Comment: @DoronG I took actions out of the Vuex.Store constructor to a separate .ts, and lost the typings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have a function type like this:

```
type MyFunc = (x: string, y: number) => boolean;
```

but which can't be used as an annotation for a general function declaration:

```
// where to annotate?    
function myFunc(x: string, y: number) {
    return x.length > y; 
}
```

It would be nice if you could annotate the function above *somehow*, like the following hypothetical syntax (which currently doesn't work):

```
// do not do this, it doesn't work:
function myFunc: MyFunc (x, y) {
    return x.length > y;
}
```

Sadly this is not currently supported in TypeScript. There is, however, an open suggestion for this feature: [microsoft/TypeScript#22063](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22063). It doesn't look like there's been any movement on that issue, but if you head over there and give it a  you might very slightly increase the chance of it being implemented.  Or, if your use case is particularly compelling and not already mentioned, you might make a comment there describing it.  Realistically this might never make it into the language.

---

So what are the workarounds?  The obvious one and the best one is to change your declared function into a declared `const` of a function type, as you've already done:

```
const myFunc: MyFunc = function (x, y) {
  return x.length > y;  
}
```

You *could* opt to use the built-in utility types [`Parameters<T>`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterst) and [`ReturnType<T>`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet) to convert the annotation of the function itself into annotation of the arguments and return type, but it's so hideous that I can't imagine anyone would prefer this to the previous version:

```
function myFunc(...[x, y]: Parameters<MyFunc>): ReturnType<MyFunc> {
    return x.length > y;
}
```

Another possibility is to try using the type system to verify that your declared function is assignable to the `MyFunc` type in a separate line.  If you have a helper type called `Extends`:

```
type Extends<T, U extends T> = void;
```

then you can do this:

```
type MyFuncWorks = Extends<MyFunc, typeof myFunc>; // okay
function myFunc(x: string, y: number) {
    return x.length > y;
}
```

and you'd see an error if you changed `myFunc` to something incompatible:

```
type MyFuncBroken = Extends<MyFunc, typeof myFunc>; // error!
// number is not boolean ---------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
function myFunc(x: string, y: number) {
    return x.length + y; // + instead of <, oops
}
```

The least ugly workaround is still the function-typed `const`, so if I were you, I'd go with that.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgYygXigCgB4C4oBnYAJwEtkBzAGihEOUQFsAjCUgSkwD4pWA9gIA2EAIbIA3AFgAUHID0CqAHcBpANZE6rRMCjIBUCYeBjg5AcnxyAZilQWrUZggcBGPIRIVqdBgYs7FxQAN5yUJFQpBDAiKTIULgAdKLUwAAWUHwgklByAL4RisqUAG5iwuQAJsQgyGa4-BDCAip2Dk6JrkhoAEyEcL3oeP7c4bJR0bHxiSlpVJnZ9DKyRfIbqFYkLm5oAMyDe+hY9mhdOLhjYRHTcQlJqRDpWTl5SlACGmIgkYVyHXOlm6xwALNhkpCANpXegAXUIAAUxKQxMxYhwiAAeIYOHicQgAJRmCQAKuAIDjjnwJlMYvc5k8Xstcv8NqBIFAAKK4YDParY0l0ACqUAgvP5RCgpL4WDKAhqqzkHOguLQAHV1FpMNyJcgBVThnQVQJbLthgBWHjvZRfH6AxzA80OC1eYhkSi0eiMIIcca3SL02aPBZLN5s5UU2DHABCpC+zx1PL5+uxatQxopps+AjARGtUA+HHjpAAhCVAmwOFByFLTPwhKIJFAALRt9vtvgAPx7vb7PYdFyEebdPk9-h9VZCtKiQYe82eiyyAGoVmygA)